# Emailing an array from html form via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, email

I'm trying to create an HTML form which allows you to create a list of people (forename, surname and their company). I want this list of people to be emailed (via PHP) along with all other data on the form.

It seems creating an array is the way to go, so I've attempted this though HTML and jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function(e)
{
    $('#namelist').append('<p  class="nameentry"><input type="text" name="cfsName[]" value="' + cName + ": " + fName + " " + sName + '" class="cfsname" disabled /> <input type="button" name="remove" class="remove" value="Remove" /></p>');
    fName = $('input[name=inputfName]').val('Forename');
    sName = $('input[name=inputsName]').val('Surname');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The HTML is added to an empty div in an array called cfsname[] (as far as I understand).

The PHP code which interprets this and should compose the email is:

```
$message = "";
if (isset($_REQUEST['visitor']) && $_REQUEST['visitor'] == "Yes")
{
    $message .= "Nature of work: Site visit" . "\n";
}
else
{
    $message .= "Nature of work: $natureofwork" . "\n";
}
$message .= "Location: $locationofwork" . "\n\n";
$message .= "Dates: $dayfrom " . "$monthfrom " . "$yearfrom " . "to $dayto " . "$monthto " . "$yearto" . "\n";
$message .= "Times: $hourfrom" . ":" . "$minfrom " . "to " . "$hourto" . ":" . "$minto" . "\n\n";
foreach($_POST['cfsName'] as $key => $value)
{
    $message .= $key . " " . $value . "\n";
}
$message .= "Project Manager: $projectmanager" . "\n";
$message .= "Contact Number: $contactnumber" . "\n";

mail(
    $emailto,
    "Worksheet Info Test",
    $message,
    $headers
);
```

The email is sent largely as expected (my 'if' loop also doesn't work, but that's not important right now), but the section which should contain the list of names taken from the array is blank. I'm clearly doing something completely wrong. Can I even call 'foreach' within the message code? is my HTML array even written properly? Should I somehow convert the HTML array into a separate PHP array?

If anyone can see any major flaws in my code (I'm sure there are many minor flaws), I'd really appreciate a shove in the right direction!

Comment: What IS wrong? How do you know something is wrong? What do you get, what do you expect? How does it differ?

Comment: The email doesn't send any of the names in the array. The whole section which should contain the names is blank. This is mentioned in my post above.

Comment: Disabled input elements will not be sent by the browser. Where do you enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not getting any of the input fields you are creating dynamically back, it is most likely because you create them "disabled".

A disabled input control MUST NOT be sent by the browser to the server. It is not a simple optical and behavioural thing. So if you do not remove the disabled flag from the input field somewhere else, they won't ever be sent.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware of that. Can I enable them as the submit button is clicked? I don't want the fields to be editable by the user...

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much, Sven. It seems it was nothing to do with my array code after all.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using for sending the form? GET or POST? Your code tries to access the variables as a post: `$_POST['cfsName']` I would use `$_REQUEST['cfsName']` to be safe.

As Mysteryos says about your JS code, "assign your variable BEFORE using them".

About a way of passing an array to PHP through a HTML form, here is a simple example:

```
<form>
a<input name="arr[]" value="a"/><br/>
b<input name="arr[]" value="b"/><br/>
c<input name="arr[]" value="c"/><br/>
d<input name="arr[]" value="d"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php

foreach ( $_REQUEST['arr'] as $item ) {
        echo "<div>$item</div>";
}
```

When sent, it would print out something like:

```
<form>
a<input name="arr[]" value="a"/><br/>
b<input name="arr[]" value="b"/><br/>
c<input name="arr[]" value="c"/><br/>
d<input name="arr[]" value="d"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The JS code should be okay - I declare them earlier in the code. I just tried your suggestion with passing the array to PHP, but it still came up blank in the email. I think part of the problem is that I'm trying to send an email message, rather than echoing HTML.

Comment: I don't think the problem has to do with sending an email or printing text. I would rather say that the variable you try to access is empty. To find out what your php code is receiving Try `$message .= print_r($_REQUEST['cfsName'], true) ;`. It will add "something" to your email.

Answer (score -1):

*(Ignore that)First of all, Each of your inputs have to have unique names.*
Secondly, assign your variable BEFORE using them.
Thirdly, i see a variable with name 'cName' but not assigned anywhere. I'll leave that up to you.
As sven said, **disabled** inputs are not sent by the browser, hence turn them into **hidden** inputs.

**Explanation:**

**javascript Code**

```
$('#add').click(function(e)
{
    fName = $('input[name=inputfName]').val('Forename');
    sName = $('input[name=inputsName]').val('Surname');
    $('#namelist').append('<p  class="nameentry">'+cName + ': ' + fName + ' ' + sName+'<input type="hidden" name="cfsName[]" value="' + cName + ": " + fName + " " + sName + '" class="cfsname"/> <input type="button" name="remove" class="remove" value="Remove" /></p>');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP Code (remains the same)**

```
...
foreach($_POST['cfsName'] as $key => $value)
{
    $message .= $key . " " . $value . "\n";
}
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The variables cName, fName and sName are declared much earlier in the JS code; the two reassignments in the click are to reset the input fields to default values. Can I ask why you've split the cName and fsName variables? My JS joins the sName, fName and sName variables to the cfsName variable so it's just one string (which I presumed would be simpler).

Comment: You are wrong. The name attribut does not have to be unique - otherwise how would radio buttons work? And naming an input element "foo[]" is a PHP special case to get an array. Perl for example would work with the name "foo".